# Deleting Images crashes Blender (using bpy)

Tags: python, image

I have written a function that denoises TGA images in batch, using Blender. My script crashes when im denoising allot of images at the same time. The cause of the crash lies in this line (so without it, it doesnt crash):

```py
bpy.data.images.remove(image)
```

I dont understand why this happens. It has something to do with the memory after rendering. I also encountered the same issue after deleting (allot of) images after baking.
So my question is: **Why does my code crash?** and **How to fix it?**

This is my full code:

```py
import bpy
import os


def bf42_TGA_denoise(pathSource, pathGenerated):
    bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True
    nodeTree = bpy.context.scene.node_tree
    nodes = nodeTree.nodes
    for node in nodes:
        nodes.remove(node)
    
    bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'TARGA_RAW'
    
    images = []
    for file in os.listdir(pathSource):
        if file.lower().endswith(".tga"):
            fileName = file.split(".",1)[0]
            
            node_image = nodes.new(type="CompositorNodeImage")
            node_denoise = nodes.new(type="CompositorNodeDenoise")
            node_output = nodes.new(type="CompositorNodeOutputFile")

            links = nodeTree.links
            new_link = links.new(node_image.outputs[0],node_denoise.inputs[0])
            new_link = links.new(node_denoise.outputs[0],node_output.inputs[0])

            image = bpy.data.images.load(os.path.join(pathSource,file))
            node_image.image = image
            images.append(image)

            node_output.base_path = os.path.join(outputDir,"TMP_Conv_"+fileName)

    
    bpy.ops.render.render()

    for image in images:
        bpy.data.images.remove(image)

    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(outputDir):
        subdirName = os.path.basename(subdir)
        if subdirName.startswith("TMP_Conv_") and files == ['Image0001.tga']:
            os.replace(os.path.join(subdir, files[0]), os.path.join(outputDir, subdirName[len("TMP_Conv_"):]+".tga"))
            os.rmdir(subdir)
```

EDIT:
the console gave this as output:

```
...
Saved: D:\....\Image0001.tga
Error   : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Address : 0x00007FF71A5F0470
Module  : C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\blender.exe
```

Comment: can you add the terminal output and any info window output that happen before the crash to your question?  I suspect you're running out of memory.

Comment: Il do so.
I edited my post